# How does one show trailing whitespace in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, whitespace

I'm looking for something like (setq show-trailing-whitespace t) in emacs, where all of the trailing whitespace is blindingly clear, ie highlighted.  My searches for this kind of option have mostly turned up examples of removing all trailing whitespace, which is not at all what I'm looking for.

Comment: A very welcome question - let's get some more activity on the answers side. I'm using Emacs, but I have colleagues using Eclipse, Xcode, and MS Visual Studio, so I'd love to pass on any information about how to visualize trailing whitespace in those editors (visualize it in a way that makes people want to remove it, like in Emacs)

Comment: By the way, I agree that automatic removal is an undesirable behavior for the editor. I wouldn't want my editor to automatically change anything that I have written.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Click on:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors
```

Then click on the link "whitespace characters" to specify what should be shown.

Comment: Is there any way to highlight the text instead of the dots?  This is much more useful now that I know I can select only trailing characters and increase the opacity, but it still isn't as glaring as the emacs version.

Comment: Dont see any way of doing that with this feature.

Comment: you win some, you lose some.  I guess I could always write my own plugin if I needed to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What I settled on for this takes a plugin but isn't bad.
Then your trailing whitespace will show up as an eclerror/warning in the file.

1: eclipse checkstyle plugin
2: make a checkstyle config as generous as you want. if you ONLY want trailing whitespace:

```
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="Regexp">
      <property name="format" value="[ \t]+$"/>
      <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
      <property name="message" value="Trailing whitespace"/>
    </module>
  </module>
</module>
```

Comment: how do you add this configuration to the plugin?